# git - how to clone my public repo while using my work account?

Tags: git, github, clone, public-key

I have a public repository (for my 'dot files') under my personal github username.

I am now using my work computer which is configured for my work account and I'm trying to clone my personal repo which is public.

When I try and clone I get

```
$ git clone git@github.com:durrantm/setups-and-dotfiles.git
Cloning into 'setups-and-dotfiles'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I clone it?  I thought the fact it was public would allow it.  Is it because my git config has my work account that I don't use at all on github? If so, what's the easier way to fix it?  I saw a post about creating a project specific git config but that didn't seem to apply as, catch-22, I can't actually clone the repository in the first place in order to then change it's config!  I guess I could rename my global config, change it, do the clone, bring back the old one, but that all seems like a crazy hack and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTTP instead of SSH to clone:

```
git clone https://github.com/durrantm/setups-and-dotfiles.git
```

Comment: That's interesting; I tested it and cloned your repo before posting this.  There's something peculiar going on with your network environment.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that was helpful.  I poked more and found that git had been complaining that it couldn't create the work tree... turned out I was playing in /tmp and on my computer I can't create directories there. Unexpected but explains my issue.

Comment: Furthermore my "git clone with the different protocol" approach didn't let me push, so I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a firewall issue? Cloning via SSH requires egress on port 22.

Comment: I thought this might be part of it, for example I disabled my VPN, but this wasn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol issue - I was using the one I usually use for private repo.

If I use the one for a public repository then it works and I don't need to switch accounts.
This is what I was looking for.

Syntax:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/durrantm/setups-and-dotfiles.git
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't do what I want as I can't then also push changes I make.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices: one is to use https or git instead of SSH to clone your repository. Or the other is to create an SSH key on your work machine add your it to your account. SSH access can't work without without a key, for unauthenticated access you need to one of the other protocols.